# How to write for loop for this pattern

Tags: gooddata

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81gxg.jpg)

Please say anyone just for loop for this pattern

Comment: Hello Badisa, welcome to stack overflow. Please provide a specific example on what you are trying to achieve, given it is unclear only from the picture. What is the desired output? Have you attempted some sort of code already, and do you  have any additional information?

Comment: Hello Badisa. To be able to provide an answer, please elaborate more on the question. Provide more inputs and example what you would like to achieve. The question is tagged with "gooddata" tag. Does it somehow relate to the GoodData SaaS Business Intelligence Platform? If so, could you please explain the relation? Thank you. M

Answer (score 1):

```perl
say join ' ', map qw( * # )[$_ % 2], 1 .. $_ for 1 .. 5;
```

Comment: Which language this one bro

Comment: Perl. If you were interested in a particular language, you should have tagged the question.

Answer (score 1):

Python:

```
for a in range(0, 5):
    for b in range(0, a+1):
        if (b%2==0):
            print("#", end=' ')
        else:
            print("*", end=' ')
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
     {
       for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
       {
        if(j%2==0)
        {
          System.out.print("#");
        }else
        {
          System.out.print("*");
        }
          
       }
       System.out.println("\n");
     }
```